# Minimise sum of increasing functions with linear constraint

Tags: maxima-minima

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two increasing continuous functions.

Given that $x_1 + x_2 = k$, show that the minimum of $f(x_1) + g(x_2)$ occurs where $f(x_1) = g(x_2)$

Comment: Let $f(x) = g(x) = x-e^{-x}$. Then $f(x_1)+g(k-x_1) = k - e^{-x_1} - e^{x_1-k}$, which has no minimum.

Comment: This question came from trying to show how the document at http://energy.gov/sites/prod/files/oeprod/DocumentsandMedia/review_of_congestion_costs_october_03.pdf can claim on page 6 that the minimum cost is achieved where the two functions intersect (it's not obvious to me). What extra constraints are required in order to prove the claim on page 6 (or is the claim just incorrect?)

Comment: The curves in the above document represent the "marginal cost of generation vs. supply", i.e. if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the costs of generation given $x$ supply in areas $A$ and $B$, respectively, then the curves drawn are $f'$ and $g'$. So the correct question to ask would be: given $x_1+x_2=k$ (and that $f'$ and $g'$ are increasing and continuous), show that the minimum of $f(x_1)+g(x_2)$ occurs where $f'(x_1)=g'(x_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure so check it please, but I think that the cost is evaluated by the integral of the two functions (in that case the area under the graph of the functions), hence if we must supply $1000$MW as constraint, the minimum of the area is when the two functions intersect each other; any other choice has a greater cost, for instance: if Area A supplies $800$MW and Area B $200$MW, the constraint is right but the cost (the integral) is equal to the minimum one plus the area between the two functions in the range $[700$MW$,800$MW$]$, so we would have a higher cost compared to the following choice: Area A supplies $700$MW and Area B $300$MW. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for your answer. However another missing piece of the puzzle is that in the US power markets the price _all_ generators are paid is the marginal cost of supply, so the cost would be a constant 1000MW x $25/MWh

Comment: Yes I read something and I think I understood that in the "new market" (market clearing price) the cost is a constant (25$/MWh, that is the intersection between the two previous functions), but this is different from the first case...maybe I didn't understand the new "problem" :-)